# Database Schema for Research Facility

Tags: database-design, database-schema

I am designing a database schema for a research facility. The database should store experimental samples with mostly predefined (dependent or independent) variables but may require project reliant variables that are unknown to the date the database is designed.

- Each sample is part of a project and some variables are only recorded if they are relevant to the specific project.
- Each recorded value should contain metadata (e.g., a timestamp and the user that recorded the value).
- Each sample has states that change over time based on specific events.
- Advanced users should be able to use the database via SQL for data analysis.

Currently, I am considering two approaches:

1. Store data in a [wide data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data), i.e. few 3NF normalized tables were columns represent variables (dependent/independent) and each row is a sample.
2. [Entity–attribute–value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) / event oriented, i.e. each recorded value is stored as an event.

Can you please recommend any of this approaches or other approaches for such a scenario? Thank you all very much for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of those approaches will fully work... With your approach 1 you cannot add new variables and while your approach 2 will work it will not be great in terms of flexibility performance or readability... also since you mention 'Advanced users should be able to use the database via SQL for data analysis' this will be very hard with this approach.

Probably the best compromise is to do a bit of both and store all the variables you currently know about as columns and then have a separate EVA (Entity Value Attribute) table where custom variables can be added. This keeps most of the logic nice, while allowing dynamic variables if required. If there is an upper-limit on the number of variables that can be added you can consider a hybrid approach of for example SpareDateVariable1Name, SpareDateVariable1Value, SpareIntegerVariable1Name, SpareIntegerVariable2Name columns on your table to allow some custom variables to be added without having to use an

The main problem is that in relational databases you are expected to know all the columns up-front. This is how they were designed. You should consider using a NoSQL solution like MongoDB which stores entries as 'documents' without a strict schema, as there is simply not a good way to address this in a traditional relational database, however these types of database will handle this scenario much better.